# users are getting sudo to root though it is blocked

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, root

I have below entries in `sudoers` file but users are getting access to root, need to block the same.

```
Cmnd_Alias      SUROOT=/bin/su -,/bin/su - root, /bin/su root, /usr/bin/su -, /usr/bin/su - root, /usr/bin/su root

kj ALL = (ALL) ALL,!SUROOT
```

but users are able to become root using below command

```
[kj@mytest-server1 ~]$ sudo su    
[sudo] password for kj:  
[root@mytest-server1 kj]#
```

I tried to block `/bin/su` but it stops user to switch to any users. After changing `sudoers` kj have below server

```
[root@mytest-server1 ~]# sudo -l -U kj 

User kj may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL, (ALL) !/bin/su -, !/bin/su - root, !/bin/su root, !/usr/bin/su
    -, !/usr/bin/su - root, !/usr/bin/su root, !/bin/su


[kj@mytest-server1 ~]$ sudo su - appeon  
[sudo] password for kj:  
Sorry, user kj is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - appeon' as root on mytest-server1.  
[kj@mytest-server1 ~]$
```

Comment: Any user that can run `sudo` will have root access. If you need users to have root permissions for certain applications without general root access, use the `SetUserID` bit on the application's permissions.

Comment: If your users can use sudo they can start programs are uid0. E.g. `sudo /usr/local/bin/bash`. Voila, a nice shell as root. It might even be a less obvious command, such as starting vim and escaping to a subshell. Or starting midnight commander, or a game of nethack. Or ...

Comment: I understand the risks but wanted to check if there is any way I can restrict users.